# Terragrunt Multiple Instances Of Module With Varying Fields

Tags: terraform, terragrunt

I'm having a very hard time trying to understand how to mirror the native Terraform module instantiation structure I am used to in Terragrunt.  Take the below Terraform structure that creates different instances of a [sns topic module](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-sns).

```
module "sns_topic" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/sns/aws"
  version = "~> 3.0"

  name  = "my-topic"
}

module "sns_topic_two" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/sns/aws"
  version = "~> 3.0"

  name  = "my-topic-two"
  content_based_deduplication              = true
}

module "sns_topic_three" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/sns/aws"
  version = "~> 3.0"

  name  = "my-topic-three"
  http_success_feedback_role_arn           = x
  http_success_feedback_sample_rate        = y
  http_failure_feedback_role_arn           = z
}
...
```

Any of the [fields in the module itself](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-sns/blob/master/main.tf#L4-L26) could populate a given instance of that module.

I don't understand how to accomplish this in Terragrunt [via their Inputs](https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/docs/features/inputs/) for cases where each instance of the module can vary by the fields uses.  For example, in the sns module, you could have Topic A that uses `content_based_deduplication` and topic B that uses `lambda_success_feedback_role_arn` and topic C that uses entirely different fields, and you might have 100 different topics in the environment.  In native Terraform you'd just instantiate each module as seen above.  But how can you do this via Terragrunt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Disclaimer: what is below just represents my understanding & workflow, which might not be definitive :) )

My understanding is that whilst you can write native Terraform in the top level module, best practice is to move this to another module, called from the `terraform` block in your `terragrunt.hcl` file. This module acts as an orchestration layer. I think the idea is that the top levels of a Terragrunt project likely represent things where you broadly want the same resources in each (for example dev, test, prod) and so the use of this orchestration module allows you to DRY that code up, rather than duplicate it between the top level directories.

Therefore in your case, I think you would need to write a module that looked a little like this and would be called from your `terragrunt.hcl` file:

**top_level/main.tf**

```
variable "sns_topics" {
  type = map(map(string))
}

module "sns_topic" {
  source   = "terraform-aws-modules/sns/aws"
  version  = "~> 3.0"
  for_each = var.sns_topics

  name                           = each.key 
  content_based_deduplication    = lookup(each.value, "content_based_deduplication", null)
  http_success_feedback_role_arn = lookup(each.value, "http_success_feedback_role_arn", null)
}
```

and then the `inputs` in your `terragrunt.hcl` might look a little like this:

```
inputs = {
  sns_topics = {
    sns_topic = {},
    sns_topic_two = {
      content_based_deduplication = true
    },
    sns_topic_three = {
      http_success_feedback_role_arn = "x"
    }
  }
}
```

Finally you would then call the `top_level` module in the `terraform` block of your `terragrunt.hcl`

```
terraform {
  source = "git::git@github.com:<your_account>/modules.git//top_level?ref=v0.0.1"
}
```

Note: the use of `null` as the default value in the `lookup` functions, should result in that parameter being omitted in the case that the specific topic map does not contain that particular key.

[This page](https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/docs/features/keep-your-terraform-code-dry/) in the Terragrunt docs talks more about this approach.